# set function on and off on one button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a button #sort where I set the sortable() jQuery UI function. It works, but I want it to have one more functionality: when I click second time on the same button I would like to disable this function. What should I do?

```
   $('#sort').click(function(){
       $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
       $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();       
   });
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'd like to remove the sortable or just disable the link so it doesn't call sortable twice ?

Comment: I would like to remove the sortable()

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$('#sort').click(function(){
   if ($("#sortable").hasClass("ui-sortable")) {
       $("#sortable").sortable("disable");
       $("#sortable").removeClass("ui-sortable");
   } else {
       $("#sortable").sortable("enable");
       $("#sortable").removeClass("ui-sortable-disabled");
   }
});
```

Comment: hmm, this is strange. Your code works fine, but only for one time, the second time i want to enable  by clicking on the same button it is not sortable any more.

Comment: @lipenco -- Try `.sortable("enable")` instead of the blank construct.

Comment: it doesn't work: after 2 click we have two classes : ui-sortable and ui-sortable-disabled

Comment: @lipenco -- Damn, going to have to write a longer logic statement, one moment.

Comment: @lipenco -- try that...we shouldn't have to remove the classes manually, but it might be causing the issue.

Comment: i am sorry;/ but it is just crazy.  when i am putting console.log after each  condition it is: enabled, disabled, enabled, enabled, enabled...

Comment: @lipenco -- Well that's frusterating. Do you mind making a fiddle with the minimal amount of code to replicate?

Comment: I got it to work! it had something to do with initialization:            $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
   $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

Comment: Ahhh, I'll remember that. I dont use jQ UI too much, but it's good to know!

Answer (score 1):

To disable sorting:

```
$("#sort").sortable('disable');
```

To enable sorting:

```
$("#sort").sortable('enable');    

    // use case
    $('#sort').click(function(){
          var isEnabled = $( "#sort" ).sortable( "option", "disabled" );
          if(isEnabled) {
           $( "#sort" ).sortable( "disable" );   // disable sorting    
       });
```

Comment: hmm, this is strange. Your code works fine, but only for one time, the second time i want to enable by clicking on the same button it is not sortable any more.

Comment: add the following line: else { $("#sort").sortable("enable"); } at second last line of code. @lipenco

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sort').click(function(){
    if (!($(this).hasClass('sortable'))){
        $("#sortable" ).sortable();
        $(this).addClass('sortable');
    }else{
        $("#sortable" ).sortable("disable" );
        $(this).removeClass('sortable');
    }     
});
```